# insert Image Datatype in Sql server table using string concatenation

Tags: sql-server, image

I have following parameters available in an stored procedure

```
@DatabaseName varchar(80)
@aImage image
@id int
```

Query i want to execute

```
set @sql =' insert into '@txtDatabase+'..Documentimages(id,image) 
             values ('+ @id +', '+ @aImage + ' )
```

The above statement does not works.

Please suggest appropriate.

Comment: Your variable name in the `DECLARE` and the `SET` are different.  Are they supposed to be?   You are also missing a + after `insert into` as well as a final single quote after the last parentheses.

Comment: You also should look at not using the image datatype. It has been deprecated since 2005. You should instead use varbinary(max). https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms187993.aspx

Answer (score 0, accepted):

My solution for this avoids concatenation by using a temp table.
Otherwise, you'd have to cast the IMAGE to a VARCHAR(MAX), with increased potential for injection attacks.

```
begin transaction 
-- SETUP stuff
use dbapp
create table dscat.dbo.Documentimages (id int, [image] VARBINARY(max))
go

-- Your Prodcedure: 
create procedure p_Test
    @DatabaseName SYSNAME,
    @aImage VARBINARY(max),
    @id int
as 
-- use a temp table to hold the data for the INSERT
SELECT @id as ID , @aImage as [aImage] INTO #ImageTemp
DECLARE @SQL VARCHAR(200)
set @sql =' insert into ['+ @DatabaseName +'].dbo.Documentimages(id,image) 
         SELECT ID, aImage FROM #ImageTemp'
EXEC (@sql)

GO

-- TEST IT: (not a valid image...)
EXEC p_test 'dscat',0xFFD8FFE000104A4649FDDC7FDF36D, 86

select *, DATALENGTH([image]) from dscat.dbo.Documentimages
ROLLBACK
```

I have also taken the liberty of using

- `VARBINARY(max)` instead of the deprecated `IMAGE` type.
- `SYSNAME` for the database name parameter
- Including `dbo` where you had `..`;  your schema may differ - but using a fully qualified name simplifies the dynamic execution.  Otherwise SQL has to go through the user/execution contexts and see which schema is the first to have the table...